# Best books on gender and racism

Tags: reference-request, contemporary-philosophy, racism

(Please excuse my poor wording and bad english)

What are the best books to learn about gender and racism as of July 2020? I feel like my generation (born between 1990 and 2005 approx) may be the first one to be changing much faster than its (socio-political) environment. I mean that (most of) today's laws are either very old or being made by somewhat old people. (I'd use the term *boomers* in all seriousness but it might not be appropiate in this forum).

I want to hear the voices of people at the heart of it all, not only (older) academics that are out of touch to what is happening "in the streets". I need to know all the arguments and points of view so that I can step out and refute ignorant coments/attitudes caused by hate and ignorance.

So I'm asking about references (mainly books and preferably translated to spanish) about the contemporary philosophy of gender, racism, the internet... I do not want to know about the metaphysics of blah blah but rather a philosophical interpretation of our time, coherent, scientific when possible and down to earth.

Thanks!!

Small edit: feel free to answer with a "learning path" of references that are easy (and cheap) to find on the internet or local bookstores

Comment: “I want to hear the voices of people at the heart of it all, not only (older) academics that are out of touch to what is happening "in the streets"” I think us older boomers have been put in our place! The free books may be older too. I still know what is going on on the mean the streets, though. 

Comment: Gender and racism are not really modern philosophical topics, rather psychological, political, sociological or historical topics today. Many philosophers from earlier days were sexist or racist (like most of the people of their time), but that's the past. Which branch of philosophy would even be relevant? metaphysics, epistemology, axiology, logic?

Comment: "It is not enough to reject wholesale the Ricardian theory of comparative cost or the Einstein theory of relativity by unmasking the alleged racial background of their authors. What is wanted is first to develop a system of Aryan logic different from non-Aryan logic. Then it would be necessary to examine point by point these two contested theories and to show where in their reasoning inferences are made which — although correct from the viewpoint of non-Aryan logic — are invalid from the viewpoint of Aryan logic."   Read more here: https://mises.org/library/what-nazis-borrowed-marx

Comment: Maybe read “Uncle Tom’s Cabin” and “Fifty shades of gray” and you’ll learn a lot.